# JQuery cannot get values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I can get a text/val from a text area. But I am trying to get an input from a Form. I've read a bunch of articles to try different things but I can only get a value/text from my textarea.

Tried serialize, get the same result.  I have a msg that prints out and my NodeJS server spits out same result on console. I've tried using classes instead of IDs.  Tried adding type="text" to customer didn't work. Tried with JSON.stringify and without for both cust and date.  Do input fields not work? I'm using JQuery 3.1.1

Response says: {date: '', customer: '""', notes: 'notes go here'}

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/sendReturnForm" id="returnForm">

        <p>Date:</p>
        <input type="date" name="formDate" id="formDate"/>
        <p>Customer:</p>
        <input name="formCustomer" id="formCustomer"/>
        <p>Notes:</p>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="notes">Notes go here</textarea>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var values = {
            date: $("#formDate").text(),
            customer: JSON.stringify($("#formCustomer").text()),
            notes: $("#notes").text()
        };

        $(".submitButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sendReturnForm',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(values),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  The data collection was in the wrong spot as pointed out by Yaroslav and Mosd.  I tried text and val but it didn't matter when I was trying to collect data that wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect data when you click submit button:

```
$(".submitButton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = {
        date: $("#formDate").val(),
        customer: JSON.stringify($("#formCustomer").val()),
        notes: $("#notes").text()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/sendReturnForm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It makes sense now seeing it laid out that the form loads and I had pre-made text in the field, which is why I was only getting that field.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$('#formCustomer') is an input field, so to get its value you need to use **$('#formCustomer').val()** instead of *$("#formCustomer").text()*

Comment: Yes text won't work but I had originally tried switching between the two. Ended up being code needed to be moved to the submit click button.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by @Yaroslav, you should be collecting the values in the onclick handler, see my code, wrapped you values in a function that i call before sending the data, also val worked for me instead of text():

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/sendReturnForm" id="returnForm">

        <p>Date:</p>
        <input type="date" name="formDate" id="formDate"/>
        <p>Customer:</p>
        <input name="formCustomer" id="formCustomer"/>
        <p>Notes:</p>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="notes">Notes go here</textarea>
        <button type='button' class='submitButton'>submit</button>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        function getValues(){
                  var values = {
            date: $("#formDate").val(),
            customer:                        JSON.stringify($("#formCustomer").val()),
            notes: $("#notes").text()
        };
        return values;
        }
        //$.each($('#returnForm').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
            //values[field.name] = field.value;
        //});
        $(".submitButton").click(function () {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(getValues()));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sendReturnForm',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(getValues()),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use the .val() function instead of the .text() to get the value from the input. see in below code. for textarea .text() is fine but for input .val() would work.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var values = {
        date: $("#formDate").val(),
        customer: JSON.stringify($("#formCustomer").text()),
        notes: $("#notes").val()
    };
    //$.each($('#returnForm').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
        //values[field.name] = field.value;
    //});
    $(".submitButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/sendReturnForm',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(values),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(values));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes text won't work but I had originally tried switching between the two. Ended up being code needed to be moved to the submit click button.